# How to enable a template class specialization when the template parameter is a bidirectional_iterator?

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae

I want to create a template class which accepts only bidirectional iterators as arguments in its constructor (which are used to initialize its data members).

I'm trying to use *enable_if* and *iterator_category* for this, but I can't understand what's going wrong. I'm using both gcc 8.3.1 and clang 7 on Linux with *-std=c++17*. I've also tried other compilers on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/5EMPvy).

(Note: I've also tried using *is_same_v* instead of *is_base_of_v*, but with the same result, or lack of...)

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<typename It>
using it_cat = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category;

template<typename BidIt,
        typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<it_cat<BidIt>, std::bidirectional_iterator_tag>> = 0
        >
class A {
    BidIt start;
public:        
//  A() : start {} {}
    A(BidIt s_) : start {s_} {}
};


// A<std::vector<int>::iterator> a1;


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v {0, 1, 2, 3};
    A a2 {v.begin()};
}
```

The two commented lines were an attempt to manually instantiate an empty object of type A by explicitly passing the parameter (without success). The compiler output clearly shows that the type deduction fails:

```
error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'

typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<it_cat<BidIt>, std::bidirectional_iterator_tag>> = 0
```

and as far as I understand the enable_if is evaluated to false.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  Your parameters to `std::is_base_of_v` are backwards and `> = 0` should be `>* = nullptr`

Answer (score 0):

First, you're using the trait backwards. [`std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) checks if the first is a base of the second. So your check should be `is_base_of_v<bidirectional_iterator_tag, it_cat<BidIt>>`.

Second, the C++17 idiom to do this kind of conditional enabling (assuming you want to have other specializations) is to have a defaulted 2nd template parameter:

```
template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct X; // the primary

template <typename T>
struct X<T, std::enable_if_t</* condition */>> // the conditional specialization
{ ... };
```

If you do *not* need a different specialization, we can do this in a simpler way:

```
template <typename T>
struct X {
    static_assert(/* the condition */, "!");
};
```

Comment: Apologies for the typo/distraction on is_base_of.

However, this solution still doesn't work for me. What kind of condition should I use in the conditional specialization? 

Now it fails with
```
<source>:11:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

<source>:29:20: note:   '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >' is not derived from 'A<It, Enable>'

     A a2 {v.begin()};
```

Comment: @JoeSilver The same condition you meant to use before: `is_base_of_v<bidirectional_iterator_tag, it_cat<Iter>>`

Comment: Yes, thanks, it works, but only if I create an object of type A passing an explicit template parameter: `A<vector<int>::iterator> a1 {v.begin()}`. I was trying to use type deduction which still, in my attempts, doesn't work.

Comment: @JoeSilver Do you _really_ need conditionally enabled specializations? Things are much simpler if you just use a `static_assert`. Otherwise, you need a deduction guide.

Comment: Well, I don't really *need* it, in fact it's a static check after all. I was trying to emulate a concept-like condition without concepts